# Django- deleting multi files of one instance of model and deleting this instance

Tags: django

For example if i want to delete all uploaded images from filesystem and database row of instance of have model like this:

```
class PictureSet(models.Model):
    image1 = models.ImageFIeld(upload_to="images/")
    image2 = models.ImageFIeld(upload_to="images/")
    image3 = models.ImageFIeld(upload_to="images/")
```

Have i any shorter possibility to do this, than
[example]:

```
picture_set1 = PictureSet.objects.get(id=1)
picture_set1.image1.delete()
picture_set1.image2.delete()
picture_set1.image3.delete()
picture_set1.delete()
```

???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest overriding model's delete method:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        if type(field) == models.ImageField:
            image = self.__getattribute__(field.name)
            image.delete()
    super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then just:

```
PictureSet.objects.get(id=1).delete()
```

Comment: This what i asking for so i accept Yuor answer. But if we are talking now about this, i ask, do You know how to delete images if there is more fields?

Comment: @Cris: I'v edited my answer. Now it should work for models with different fields.

Comment: No, this not work for me, but i don't unaccept Your answer because it gives some new look for me. Thank You for that. Erros is: `AttributeError: 'ImageField' object has no attribute 'delete'`

Comment: Notice that when using `PictureSet.objects.filter(...).delete()` **will not** call the `.delete()` method.

Comment: @Pill: Thank You. Your delete() function deleting right slq column and right images from filesystem.
@Mandx: I noticed that. Function can has name like `delete_images` and when it is specified in model structure and hasn't `super(self.__class__, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)` it only removing images so You can easly then call `delete()` if You want remove sql row.

Answer (score 0):

```
picture_set = PictureSet.objects.get(id=1)
picture_set1.delete()
```

deletes the whole pictureset class no need to delete everything...

if the pictures themselves stay there just implement some kind of cleaning functions which checks againstthe upload folder and the image links stored in database

hope this helps

Comment: `picture_set1.delete()` deliting only database row, not images. I don't have specified any additional delete() function so i thinks i need specified it.

Comment: what i did in my last project i implement a cleaning function that runs ones a day and removes any data that was not needed anymore thats why i did it like this

Comment: something like deamon process?

Comment: i guess, i used a friends project wich handles time specific tasks and that helped